# Can not resolve symbol ExecuteMethodCall (linq to sql)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I study Linq to sql from blog scottgu and I get the error message:

> "Can not resolve symbol ExecuteMethodCall".

Method ExecuteMethodCallis is supported by linq to sql, but why does this error appear?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.VariableShapeSample
        (
    @shape int 
    )

AS
    if(@shape=1)
    select * from products
    else if (@shape=2)
    select * from orders
```

---

```
public partial class NorthwindDataContext
{
    [Function(Name = "VariableShapeSample")]
    [ResultType(typeof (Product))]
    [ResultType(typeof (Order))]
    public IMultipleResults VariableShapeSample(System.Nullable<int> shape )
    {

        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this
                                                       , ((MethodInfo) (MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))
                                                       , shape);

        return (IMultipleResults) result.ReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's way too much whitespace in that code block

Comment: but on second thought, it might not be your fault.  it's probably markdown's fault

Answer (score 0):

[DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb493883.aspx) method is an internal method. You can't call it. It is are accessible only within files in the System.Data.Linq assembly. Well, you can use reflection to call it, if you really need to:

```
Type type = typeof(NorthwindDataContext);
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ExecuteMethodCall", 
                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var currentMethod = ((MethodInfo) (MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()));
var result = (IExecuteResult)methodInfo.Invoke(this, 
                                 new object[] { this, currentMethod, shape });
```

Comment: @azyberezovsky:  what is the `currentMethod` ? how can i return value `return (IMultipleResults) result.ReturnValue;`? please, explain clearly. thanks a lot!

Comment: @azyberezovsky: Thanks a lot!
Once this method is added into project we can then call it and convert the result to be either a Product or Order sequence when we are using it[link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: @Jack if you want to call stored procedure, best way to do that is just generate method for it and call like `context.CustOrderHist("ALFKI")`

Comment: @azyberezovsky: I want to return `IMultipleResults`, but your code return `ISingleResults`!

Comment: @Jack that's the result of `VariableShapeSample` execution. What shape value you have passed?

Comment: @azyberezovsky: I want to return `IMultipleResults`, but your first code return `ISingleResults`!
please help me? how to solve this problem in order to following code to be worked:
<pre> IMultipleResults results1 = db.VariableShapeSample(1);
            products = results1.GetResult<Product>();

IMultipleResults results2 = db.VariableShapeSample(2);
            products = results2.GetResult<Order>(); <code>
**see the above procedure**

Comment: @Jack again, my code just calls your stored procedure. It's your procedure returning `ISingleResult` instead of `IMultipleResults`